# How to write an auto incrementing number into another table value? Is this possible?

Tags: php, mysql

On INSERT is there a way to write the auto incrementing item_id number from table/items into table/photos item_id?

```
+---------------+  +---------------+
|     items     |  |     photos    |
+---------------+  +---------------+
| int/auto incr |  |      int      |
|    item_id    |  |    item_id    |
+---------------+  +---------------+
|     int       |  |      int      |
|   member_id   |  |   member_id   |
+---------------+  +---------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can get it easily last inserted id of items table and use it for next

**Using php :-**

after insert query use

```
insert into items () values (1);
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();`
```

and insert another table `$last_id`

**Using mysql:-**

there is a function to insert  [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: If two users insert concurrently, will this function keep them seperate?

Comment: yeah will be seperate

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the last autoincrement value for that connection, so be sure to issue it on the same connection as the previous insert.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the first qry then declared $last_id='last_insert_id()' then second qry and it worked great! @Marcus Adams

Answer (score 1):

Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

```
insert into items (member_id) values (1);
insert into photos (item_id, member_id) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 1);
```